# Vuex duplicate values in nested object mutations

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am having this issue with Vuex:

I am trying to mutate a nested object in my module state. When I do the mutation it sets the value in all the objects nested properties in my module state.

I dynamically set the collection objects. My module state:

```
collection: [{
    id: 1,
    prop: {
      nestedProp: ""
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    prop: {
      nestedProp: ""
    },
  },
]
```

When I properly mutate the state in the mutations methods, it duplicates the value:

```
changeValueById(state) {
    const obj = state.collection.find(obj => obj.id === 1)
    obj.prop.nestedProp = "new value!!"
}
```

The espected value:

```
// colletion[0].prop.nestedProp === "new value!!"
// colletion[1].prop.nestedProp === ""
// colletion[2].prop.nestedProp === ""
```

But I get:

```
// colletion[0].prop.nestedProp === "new value!!"
// colletion[1].prop.nestedProp === "new value!!" (duplicated)
// colletion[2].prop.nestedProp === "new value!!" (duplicated)
```

Am I mutating the state in the wrong way? I can't understand why it is duplicating the value y the whole state tree.

Comment: Maybe try replacing your current mutator function with something like this:
state.collection = state.collection.map(item => {if (item.id===1) item.prop.nestedProp = 'new new value'})
Maybe others can confirm, but my suspicion is that there's something about Vue internals that don't let you set state by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutation looks fine. It looks like the child objects in your state (`prop`) have the same reference. Check the code where you set the `prop` values. If it looks something like this:

```
let prop = {nestedProp: ''}
collection = [{id: 1, prop: prop}, {id: 2, prop: prop}] // Using the same instance of prop in each element of the array!
```

then this would explain the problem. You could fix this by cloning the value each time you set it. Something like:

```
let prop = {nestedProp: ''}
collection = [{id: 1, prop: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prop))}, {id: 2, prop: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prop))}]
```

Comment: Was the reference indeed. Thanks a lot.